# Deleting 2 spaces in Overleaf when pressing delete once [Latex]

Tags: latex

When I press the backspace button once in the text editor in overleaf it will delete the previous two spaces. I want it to delete only one space. I can't seem to find anyone with a similar problem. Is there something in the settings I can change so it doesn't so this anymore? 
Thanks

Comment: Did you type `tab` instead a double space?

Comment: I suggest also to move the question to https://tex.stackexchange.com/, which is dedicated exactly to TeX, LaTeX and simila.